# WinRT: Check if TextBox Input Data does not contain symbols

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to check my text box input data contains symbols or not.
I have Implemented this

```
public static Boolean NumericTextBox(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isTrue = false;
    //string _dot=".",_comma=",",_staric="*",_and="&",_power="^",_dollar="$",_percentage="%";
    string[] symbols = { ".", ",", "(", ")", "*", "*", "-", "^", "%", "#", "@","!" };

    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(), "\\d+"))
    {
        return isTrue = true; 
    }
    else if (symbols.Contains(e.Key.ToString()))
    {
        return isTrue = false;
    }

    return isTrue;
}
```

My first condition successfully works fine but upon symbols array it doesn't matches that.
Need Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.Key` is a `VirtualKey` enum type and `enum.ToString()` returns a string representation of an enum. There is no such `VirtualKey` value as `VirtualKey..` or `VirtualKey.,` since that would be invalid syntax. You could check what the `VirtualKey` values for these keys are and make symbols a `VirtualKey` array instead of a string array. You could also just check the contents of the `Text` property of your `TextBox` since it will already contain the symbol typed by the time you get the `KeyDown` event. Note that the user might have just pasted in a value that includes one of the symbols and `e.Key` would probably just be `VirtualKey.V` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here you go.

```
var textbox = new TextBox
{
    Text = "$1,234.00"
};
var number = default(double);
if (double.TryParse(textbox.Text, out number))
{
    // parse success
}
else
{
    // parse fail
}
```

No question, this is the easiest approach.

Best of luck!